# Updating Table with SUM of column values where a field is identical

Tags: sql

I've been trying to find a way on how to do this. I currently have a table that has the columns Progress and User. Ideally, each user has a different number of rows ON the table determining the progress in small bits, but I'd like to find a way to add another column called ProgressByUser, which stores the sum of the Progress Values of that same User. Is there a way I can do this without using a cursor?

Comment: Why would you do that? You would have to update it every time the table changes.

Comment: This is being used for stored procedure purposes. I forgot to mention that it is a Temporary Table.

Comment: Please, be more specific. Give some example.

Comment: Please share your table and give us more information about what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select t1.user, t1.progress, t2.total_progress
from your_temp_table t1
join
(
   select user, sum(progress) as total_progress
   from your_temp_table 
   group by user
) t2 on t1.user = t2.user
```

The inner select gets the sum for each user. Join against that to get all the data.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks. I'm new to group by's so it took a while to get it.